# Does anyone know what specific plane this is a model of?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Curious about the one 6 seconds in on this compilation of flutter experiments

Comment: Considering it failed, I'm fairly sure it isn't a model of a existing (at that time) real airliner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it is a B-52.

The YouTube description also says that one of the aircraft is a B-52.

[image]

[Kev Cook B-52 Flickr photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/infinity-and-beyond/52137629954)
[image]

When I saw the tail, the B-52 immediately came to mind.
[image]

Wikipedia XB-52 photo
[image]

Comment: I thought about this as well, but it seems odd that all 8 engines are missing. I think the weight and aerodynamic influence of engines is rather important for aero-structural experiments

Comment: Also the plane in the video has considerably wider wing root, and a different fuselage cross section and overall form.

Comment: the thin swept wings on the B52 were very controversial and a cause of concern. This was most likely a test of an early design. The amount of flex in a B52 wing is almost unbelievable. It caused many issues over the years. The wing tans were originally drop tanks, but dropping them would have caused the wing tips to flutter. Tip gear had to be added to prevent the wings from hitting the ground. The B52 also had wet wings, the skin of the wings were part of the fuel tanks. Given the amount of flex we always had fuel leaks. Especially we add the weight of the ALCM pylons under the wings.

Comment: It looks B-52ish but may be some sort of generic design fit scientific study in a wind tunnel than aerodynamic research for an actual production aircraft.